# Confusion between curvilinear and rectilinear coordinate

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, coordinate-systems

This is perhaps an elementary question to ask, but it is important for me.

I am confused between [curvilinear coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates) and [rectilinear coordinates](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=rectilinear+coordinates). Are these two same things? (Synonym of each other?) Or there actually is some difference in between them.

Comment: A rectilinear coordinate system is such that the metric tensor components are constants. Or alternatively, if your space is a linear (vector) space, then it is a coordinate system that is defined by a global basis of the vector space (a *linear* map from your vector space to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (this definition needs no metric). A curvilinear coordinate system is any local diffeomorphism from your space into $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you have a metric, your metric componenets will be functions in a curvilinear system.

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't understand all these mathematical terms as I am only beginning to study these topics on my own. So can you simplify the answer? I mean, even an yes/no answer will do good too at this moment. I will refer to this answer of yours after I get to study the subject in more details. But right now I need to know, whether rectilinear and curvilinear coordinate systems are same or there is some difference! Kindly answer in yes/no. (I mean no disrespect but my level of understanding is very preliminary.)

Comment: Rectilinear coordinates have straight coordinate lines whose scaling is constant. The coordinate axes don't have to meet at right angles, and *different* coordinate axes don't need to have the same scaling, but each axis will have a constant scaling.

Curvilinear coordinates have curvy coordinate lines whose scalings can change.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. Now, I cannot help but ask that can I think of rectilinear coordinates to be a special case of curvilinear coordinates?

Comment: You're correct.